# Can a simple Logging of Cursor change entire program behavior?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, logging

Consider this Method in a DatabaseHelper class:

```
public Cursor getRules()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Rules",new String [] {}); 
    Log.d("Cursor Size", "" + cur.getCount());
    db.close();
    return cur;
}
```

It returns a Cursor and on the activity, I consume it like

```
    Cursor ruleCursor=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this).getRules();
    if(ruleCursor!=null)
    {
        RuleManager.getInstance(this,null).loadRules(ruleCursor);
        ruleCursor.close();
    }
```

(I am not moving the entire cursor handling inside the DatabaseHelper class and return just a list of Objects instead of cursor), the problem is that if I don't Log.d in getRules(), entire program fails.  i get an "Invalid Statement in fillWindow()" error, and SQLite doesn't return any row on a "Select" statement.

Just adding a Log.d for cursor.getCount() solves everything.  Also, to mention, this thing was working fine till yesterday and is behaving like this from the last evening.

Am I missing something? Is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

//Stop worrying about the DatabaseHelper here.

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    Cursor c=getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from RULES", null);
    return c;
}
```

//and where ever you use the Cursor(or "Consume" your cursor) just.

```
c=db.getAllRows();
startManagingCursor(c);
```

Hope it helps you!!